# Python pandas: concatenated column lookup

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation, lookup

Working with a python pandas dataframe based on Google Analytics data:

```
Customer | medium   | dollars | date
ABC        cpc         43       04062015
ABC        cpc         35       05042015
BCD        cpc         25       02012015
BCD        referral    15       01112015
CDE        referral    67       03262015
CDE        organic     66       04042015
CDE        organic     15       03062015
DEF        organic     33       07092015
DEF        referral    90       01052015
DEF        cpc         57       04122015
```

You can see that Customer ABC transacted only through cpc, while customer BCD transacted through cpc and referral.

For correct aggregations, I need to add the following column

```
Customer | medium   | dollars | date       |medium_year
ABC        cpc         43       04062015    cpc
ABC        cpc         35       05042015    cpc
BCD        cpc         25       02012015    cpc, referral
BCD        referral    15       01112015    cpc, referral
CDE        referral    67       03262015    referral, organic
CDE        organic     66       04042015    referral, organic
CDE        organic     15       03062015    referral, organic
DEF        organic     33       07092015    organic, referral, cpc
DEF        referral    90       01052015    organic, referral, cpc
DEF        cpc         57       04122015    organic, referral, cpc
```

I basically am working towards a pivot, where I can summarize client KPIs or unique client counts by all the iterations of the column "medium".

- cpc only
- referral only
- organic only
- cpc & referral
- cpc & organic
- referral & organic
- cpc, referral & organic

It is important, that the above values are unique in the column, so it's not "cpc & referral" once and "referral & cpc" once. It doesn't matter what the format is - & or commas; whatever is easiest.

I probably need to create a lookup table, something like this:

```
Customer |medium_year
ABC        cpc only
BCD        cpc, referral
CDE        referral, organic
DEF        organic, referral, cpc
```

Once I have that I could use .loc or lookup. But how do I create the lookup table? Or is there an easier way altogether? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a `groupby()` and `transform()`, e.g.:

```
>>> df['medium_year'] = df.groupby('Customer')['medium'].transform(lambda x: ', '.join(set(x)))
>>> df
  Customer    medium  dollars     date             medium_year
0      ABC       cpc       43  4062015                     cpc
1      ABC       cpc       35  5042015                     cpc
2      BCD       cpc       25  2012015           cpc, referral
3      BCD  referral       15  1112015           cpc, referral
4      CDE  referral       67  3262015       referral, organic
5      CDE   organic       66  4042015       referral, organic
6      CDE   organic       15  3062015       referral, organic
7      DEF   organic       33  7092015  referral, organic, cpc
8      DEF  referral       90  1052015  referral, organic, cpc
9      DEF       cpc       57  4122015  referral, organic, cpc
```

Comment: thank you very much - how do I avoid "cpc, referral" and "referral,cpc" - should I just sort by customer and medium beforehand?

Comment: you could do `sorted(set(x))` if `set(x)` doesn't return things in a consistent order.